# Can we create google spreadsheet having multiple sheets by using Google Drive API

Tags: c#, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

Currently, we are creating spreadsheet using DriveService. It creates spreadsheet with single sheet. Code used is as follows:

```
DriveService service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { HttpClientInitializer = credential, ApplicationName = applicationName }); 
Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File body = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File();
body.Title = uploadSpreadsheetRequest.FileName;
body.Description = uploadSpreadsheetRequest.FileName;
body.MimeType = "text/csv";
byte[] byteArray=System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(uploadSpreadsheetRequest.FilePath);
System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);
FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, "text/csv");
request.Convert = true;
request.Upload();
```

Is there any way, that I can modify my code to create a spreadsheet with multiple sheets.

I am able to do this by using Google Sheets API, but i want that to happen by using bytes.

Can someone please help me on this.

Comment: I don't think so.  Note you might want to check out V3 of the Google Drive api no reason to be using the older version really.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this. I used [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) for creating excel file having multiple sheets, and then uploaded that file using google drive by setting the content type as 'application/vnd.ms-excel'.

Used NOPI as Microsoft Excel is not installed on production servers.